# Validate a path within the site?

Tags: 7, uri

I'm working on a module that accepts user-specified paths for special treatment. I want to have a validation step where I check whether that path actually exists on the site.

Is doing a query to the `menu_router` table sufficient? Is there a better way -- say, a Drupal function -- to validate a url?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the code for [menu_edit_item_validate()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!menu!menu.admin.inc/function/menu_edit_item_validate/7), which is the function that validates the input from the user when creating a new menu item, you will notice it calls [drupal_valid_path()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_valid_path/7). If that function is not enough, you could look at the code of `menu_edit_item_validate()` to see if that code can be useful to create your own validation function.

```
  $normal_path = drupal_get_normal_path($item['link_path']);
  if ($item['link_path'] != $normal_path) {
    drupal_set_message(t('The menu system stores system paths only, but will use the URL alias for display. %link_path has been stored as %normal_path', array('%link_path' => $item['link_path'], '%normal_path' => $normal_path)));
    $item['link_path'] = $normal_path;
  }
  if (!url_is_external($item['link_path'])) {
    $parsed_link = parse_url($item['link_path']);
    if (isset($parsed_link['query'])) {
      $item['options']['query'] = drupal_get_query_array($parsed_link['query']);
    }
    else {
      // Use unset() rather than setting to empty string
      // to avoid redundant serialized data being stored.
      unset($item['options']['query']);
    }
    if (isset($parsed_link['fragment'])) {
      $item['options']['fragment'] = $parsed_link['fragment'];
    }
    else {
      unset($item['options']['fragment']);
    }
    if ($item['link_path'] != $parsed_link['path']) {
      $item['link_path'] = $parsed_link['path'];
    }
  }
  if (!trim($item['link_path']) || !drupal_valid_path($item['link_path'], TRUE)) {
    form_set_error('link_path', t("The path '@link_path' is either invalid or you do not have access to it.", array('@link_path' => $item['link_path'])));
  }
```

If you need to verify if the anonymous user has access to the menu item, you can use code similar to the following one:

```
drupal_save_session(FALSE);
$original_user = $GLOBALS['user'];
$GLOBALS['user'] = drupal_anonymous_user();

$result = drupal_valid_path($link, TRUE);

$GLOBALS['user'] = $original_user;
drupal_save_session(TRUE);
```

To change the code I shown from `menu_edit_item_validate()`, you should rewrite the last control statement as the following code.

```
  drupal_save_session(FALSE);
  $original_user = $GLOBALS['user'];
  $GLOBALS['user'] = drupal_anonymous_user();

  if (!trim($item['link_path']) || !drupal_valid_path($item['link_path'], TRUE)) {
    form_set_error('link_path', t("The path '@link_path' is either invalid or you do not have access to it.", array('@link_path' => $item['link_path'])));
  }

  $GLOBALS['user'] = $original_user;
  drupal_save_session(TRUE);
```

This is the only possibility you have, if you don't want to rewrite all the code Drupal uses to verify if a user has access to a menu item, as that code verifies the currently logged-in user has access to the menu item, not a user for which the user object is passed to the code.

Comment: `drupal_valid_path()` won't work for my purposes because the documentation says it checks if the current user has access to it. In my case, a person with administrative rights will be setting things up for anonymous users. So it looks like I will be drawing from this function.

Comment: See the updated answer.

Comment: Actually, I need to validate some urls that are not accessible by the anonymous user, but nonetheless exist. So it looks like I will be re-writing the function... :P

Comment: Thanks. It's work for me too! I trusted that `drupal_valid_path()` validates node path, but it doesn't and I didn't look into `drupal_valid_path()`. Anyway, thanks!